# Mapping of index-property does not work

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, mapping

I have this problem:

Suppose I have a User, and his is the property of Cards:

```
public class User: Entity
{
...
public virtual IList<Card> Cards { get; set; }
...
}

<class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="Id" column="UserId">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <version name="Version"/>
    ...
    <list name="Cards" cascade="all" inverse="true">
      <key column="ViolatorId" not-null="true"/>
      <index column="CardIndex"/>
      <one-to-many class="Card"/>
    </list>
    ...
</class>
```

Then I get the user from the database, add it to the list of cards one card and call session.Update ().

Generated this sql-code:

```
INSERT INTO Cards
            (Version,
             ViolatorId,
             ModeratorId,
             IssueDate,
             TermDate,
             Cause,
             Type,
             CardId)
VALUES      (1 /* @p0_0 */,
             '6872df65-a1d7-40ef-abec-c14af96f3388' /* @p1_0 */,
             '06060a30-252a-4f29-84fe-af5da110f049' /* @p2_0 */,
             '2011-11-06T17:20:11.00' /* @p3_0 */,
             '2011-11-06T22:20:11.00' /* @p4_0 */,
             'Ad personam' /* @p5_0 */,
             'Red' /* @p6_0 */,
             '0454bbba-5ec9-429f-8830-d9cc33588f7a' /* @p7_0 */)
```

The problem is that, the request does not contain the value of CardIndex, and fills it in the database as NULL.

How to make NHibernate to work correctly?

Comment: Of course, I can use Bag in this case, but in the project I have similar examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Fluent NHibernate mapping for defining entity mappings. In your case you have one-to-many relation between the Users and Cards entity. For cascade save/update/delete to work properly, you will have to define proper two mapping between, the two entities. Also, the Cards entity, should have a reference, to the Users entity. Refer to the following link for how this type of mapping is defined(in C#) using Fluent NHibernate :

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#HasMany_.2F_one-to-many
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one

Although the code is given in C# but I assume it should not be very difficult for you to understand as whats going on.

You can also try the following approach for cascade saving parent child relationship kind of entities.

```
public void Test()
{
    using (IStatelessSession statelessSession = _sessionManager.OpenStatelessSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = statelessSession.BeginTransaction())
        {
            statelessSession.Insert(<ParentEntity>);
            foreach(var childEntity in ParentEntity)
            {
                statelessSession.Insert(<childEntity>);
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }       
    }
}
```

But again, for this to work properly, your mapping should be clearly defined.

Comment: Fluent is nice, but now totally on his move or make a mess in the project I do not want. But anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I use Fluent NHibernate, so I used that as a medium for sharing my knowledge. The idea of mapping is actually same and at run-time(not sure if its run time or compile time), the Sql generated will be exactly same.

Comment: I understand this, I just want to find what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I am missing some attribute?